# Using Constant component for styling your main component in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications

I've looked everywhere and tried every search I could think of but cannot seem to find this one. I need to make a Constant component in react that holds a bunch of constant styles. they need to be for instance color, backgroundColor,and padding.

I cannot seem to get it to work with just making a constant here's and example

```
export const EXPANSION_PANEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR = {backgroundColor:#DFDEDE};
```

and then I import it into my main component like

```
import EXPANSION_PANEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR from './constants.jsx'
```

and the way i use it is like

```
<ExpansionPanel style={{ EXPANSION_PANEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR }}
```

when I load my local host it does not display the desired color. any ideas on what I can do ?

Comment: Consider accepting an answer if you feel any of them answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

`{{ EXPANSION_PANEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR }}` desugars into `{{ EXPANSION_PANEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR: EXPANSION_PANEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR }}`. You just want to use the object, not use it as value for the `EXPANSION_PANEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR` key:

```
<ExpansionPanel style={EXPANSION_PANEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because the way you wrote means:

```
<ExpansionPanel style={{ EXPANSION_PANEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR:  EXPANSION_PANEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR}}
```

Style needs an object and `EXPANSION_PANEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR` is an object, so you need to write it like this:

```
<ExpansionPanel style={ EXPANSION_PANEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR }  // no {{ only single {
```

Consider this simple example:

```
const EXPANSION_PANEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR = {backgroundColor:#DFDEDE};

<ExpansionPanel style={ EXPANSION_PANEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR }
```